# String custom formatter .NET

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatting

I have one trouble with custom formatting string.
I want to make smth like that:

```
var str = "SOME_ORIGINAL_FIELD_NAME";
var format1 = "XX_X_X";
var format2 = "X_XXX";

var strFormat1 = String.Format(str, format1); // SOMEORIGINAL_FIELD_NAME
var strFormat2 = String.Format(str, format2); // SOME_ORIGINALFIELDNAME
```

Does anybody know the right direction for searching? Maybe I should look at IFormatProvider and ICustomFormatter side.

Comment: Can you provide expected input and output clearly please?

Comment: input: string = "SOME_ORIGINAL_FIELD_NAME"; format = "XX_X_X"; 
output: string = "SOMEORIGINAL_FIELD_NAME". 
Every "X" is the word. And I want to delete underscores between words like at pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `X`'s in the format string with successive placeholders, and split the input string value into a string array, then apply `string.Format()`:

```
public static string FormatSplitAndJoin(string input, string formatTemplate, string delimiter = "_", string placeholder = "X")
{
    // split "a_b_c" into ["a", "b", "c"]
    var parts = input.Split(delimiter);

    // turn "X_X_X" into "{0}_{1}_{2}"
    var index = 0;
    var formatString = Regex.Replace(formatTemplate, placeholder, m => string.Format("{{{0}}}", index++));

    // validate input length
    if(index > parts.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("input string resulted in fewer arguments than expected, {0} placeholders found", index));

    // apply string.Format()
    return string.Format(formatString, parts);
}
```

Now you can do:

```
var str = "SOME_ORIGINAL_FIELD_NAME";
var format1 = "XX_X_X";
var format2 = "X_XXX";

var strFormat1 = FormatSplitAndJoin(str, format1); // SOMEORIGINAL_FIELD_NAME
var strFormat2 = FormatSplitAndJoin(str, format2); // SOME_ORIGINALFIELDNAME
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you just have to:

- split the source string into its components,
- use `{i}` placeholders instead of `X`, and
- reverse the parameters to `String.Format` (format is first, data follows).

Example code ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/deQexG)):

```
var components = "SOME_ORIGINAL_FIELD_NAME".Split('_');
var format1 = "{0}{1}_{2}_{3}";
var format2 = "{0}_{1}{2}{3}";

var strFormat1 = String.Format(format1, components); // SOMEORIGINAL_FIELD_NAME
var strFormat2 = String.Format(format2, components); // SOME_ORIGINALFIELDNAME
```

Comment: +1 for non-regex solution - even though `format1` & `format2` have changed, OP probably had the same intention